# Expectation value of the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hamiltonian, hydrogen

How to calculate  expectation value of the Hamiltonian for hydrogen atom?
$$\langle H \rangle_{\alpha l} \equiv \frac{\langle \psi_{\alpha l m}|H(r)| \psi_{\alpha l m}\rangle}  {\langle \psi_{\alpha l m} |\psi_{\alpha l m}\rangle }   $$
Where $$\psi_{\alpha l m}=r^le^{-\alpha  r^2}Y^m_l(\theta,\phi)$$
and
$$H(r)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2-\frac{e^2}{r}$$

Comment: Do the math.  I assume you know calculus or you wouldn't be considering this problem.

Comment: Basically [cross posted on mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104711/expected-value-of-a-hamiltonian).